# Vlookup into master workbook from different workbooks

Tags: excel, vlookup

There is master workbook containing extensive information pertaining to 5 people who handle different accounts (companies). These 5 people filter by their name and update information of their related accounts and send back their copy of master workbook to me. They highlight the account names where the updates have been done.

I have to incorporate their updates in the master workbook that i maintain.
I am currently doing manually by filtering their name in master workbook and copying updates of the highlighted color accounts to the Master.

Can i do a vlookup here? what is a more effective way? 
I am learner with vlookup and only know how to do it from one sheet to another not from Multiple to single workbook.

Kindly help[image: This is what i am looking at]

Answer (score 0):

You can use vlookup on multiple workbooks.

```
=VLOOKUP(D1,[Book2]Sheet1!$C$1:$F$22,1,FALSE)
```

In the sample above, lookup the value on D1, in the table $C$1:$F$22 in sheet1 in Book2.xls.
In your case: just point to the table in the master workbook while you typing the formula. Excel will do it automatically.

Comment: I think @khan88 wants that only highlighted rows sholud be copied.

Comment: Yes, i only want to copy the details of highlighted row into the master. Like only the updates (Details, address, billing, comments) of companies 6,11,4,9,2,7 to be copied into Master

Comment: I am not familiar with VBA but I can give a try if you can tell me how to do it